# c# How do I catch Windows Form Events in user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a user control for search. In the time of searching a popup will open. Now I want to access ***Form_Resize*** and ***Form_LocationChanged*** event from the user control.

Comment: Have you any code to provide so we can see what you've already tried?

Comment: Accessing the properties of the control switching with the lighting icon to events and assigning what ever you want is not working somehow? ... You don't know about that, or is there something missing in your question?

Comment: I dont know it. I am new in c#.

Comment: I am trying to explain the scenario. User control is added to windows forms. In user control there is a textbox. when I am writing anything a popup will open. under the textbox. But when I am re sizing the form the popup position is not changing and the same thing occur when I am dragging the form. I want to close the popup in both the cases without raising those events from the form.  if(usercontrol.parent.location change occur) {popup.close }.      i want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Control constructor, you have to subscribe to `ParentChanged` event of the control to know when you can get your controls current parent.

```
public YourControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ParentChanged += OnParentchanged;
}

private void OnParentchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // maybe get Form istead of just parent control
    Parent.Resize += OnParentResize;
    Parent.LocationChanged += OnParentLocationChanged;
}
```

Then you have to subscribe to the form's events that you need. 
The thing is, that `Parent` of your control might be another control, so you may want to recursively search all `Parents` until it's form. It is just not that really that clear what do you want to achieve.

Also, remember that you have unsubscribe from events of a previous parent if it changes. But that's another and a very tricky question.

**EDIT:**
You don't need to recursively search for the form by yourself, there is a `FindForm()` method, that was mentioned by @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

Every control has a `FindForm` method that will return the form that contains the control, even if there are other controls in between in the hierarchy.  Once you have a reference to the form, you can handle its events in exactly the same way as you would any other object's at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The Parent object might be null if you try to access it from the constructor. What I had to do was add the reference in the Load event for the UserControl.

```
private void CustomControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    ParentChanged += OnParentChanged;
}

private void OnParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Parent.Resize += OnParentResize;
    Parent.LocationChanged += OnParentLocationChanged;
    // More events or
    // Do Something...
}
```